# Selenium Webdriver assert 2 elements contains same number in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, assert

I have two web elements, for example:

element 1:

```
<p>Account balance:
     <br>
     <span class="bold">5000$</span>                           
</p>
```

element 2:

```
<div id="account">        
    <a title="Upgrade now" href="#">5000$</a>
</div>
```

I want to assert them if they have the same number (5000$). I am trying with xpath, but it doesn't work.

xPath to find element 1: `//*[text()[contains(.,'5000$')]]`

xPath to find element 2: `//a[text()[contains(.,'5000$')]]`

Comment: Could you please add in your question what you have already tried with xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First element: `"//span[text()='5000$']"`

Second element: `"//a[text()='5000$']"`